# Convert python list to string

Tags: python

I have a python list like so:

```
list = []
for loop
   list.append("blah")
```

What I want to do it convert this list to string with each value separated by comma.

How do I do this??

Comment: do you mean to convert `['a', 'b', 'c']` to `'a, b, c'`??

Comment: You should generally do a quick Google and/or StackOverflow search before asking questions like this. Not only does the Python documentation answer this, but this question has also been asked many times before.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
','.join(your_list)
```